# Local logon script - check group membership and action

Tags: groups, logon-scripts, logoff

I need some help for a side project I'm working on.
I hardly deal with any scripting so I thought you guys could help me out.
The script should follow this algorithm:

1. check if user is a member of -AD group-
2. if positive force logoff
3. if negative proceed with logon

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention this script is a "local login script" which implies you only want a select machine to deny users of your AD group the ability to log on. Rather than relying on a script to log the user off you could prevent them logging on at all by adding a GPO to the machine with the AD group added in the following location:

```
Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment
```

I can't check at the moment but I'm sure you can add groups to this policy as well as users.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but unfortunately my sys admin wouldn't give me permissions to edit the gpo.
I'm actually the helpdesk taking some side projects.

Comment: You could make this change in Local Security Policy too if GPO isn't any good.